# PyCharm not exporting the correct requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm

I created a project in PyCharm that uses flask (among a few other modules) installed in a PyCharm-created virutal environment of Python 3.6.1, and the app itself works great in PyCharm. When I went to set up a requirements.txt file for other virtual requirements, however, I noticed that only `virtualenv` was listed in the output file. (To create the file, I went to "console" and did "pip freeze > requirements.txt".)

After testing some things out, I noticed that `pip list` only gave me three modules installed to begin with. I know this is not true because when I go into the settings of my interpreter, PyCharm says there are a lot of other modules installed, but it doesn't seem like they're *actually* installed.

How can I create a requirements file in PyCharm effectively? Do I just have to list all the modules I installed in my readme and have my users figure out how to install them all themselves?

Screenshots below:

**Project Settings dialog:**
[image: Project Settings]

**Pip list output:**
[image: pip list]

Answer (score 9):

**Use pipreqs**

```
$ pip install pipreqs
$ pipreqs /home/project/location
Successfully saved requirements file in /home/project/location/requirements.txt
```

This will export the packages used in your current project directory into requirements.txt

See [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs)

**Why not pip freeze?**

- pip freeze only saves the packages that are installed with pip
  install in your environment.
- pip freeze saves all packages in the
  environment including those that you don't use in your current
  project. (if you don't have virtualenv)
- Sometimes you just need
  to create requirements.txt for a new project without installing
  modules.

Comment: pipreqs doesn't seem to work. It just throws an error about being unable to decode a character.

Comment: @BenSchwabe Can you try with `--encoding=utf-8` option, and see if the error persists

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly strange, the only thing I can think of is that it's a problem with `virtualenv` on Windows.

Anyways it wouldn't be best practice to create your `requirements.txt` from `pip freeze`, because you have more packages installed than the ones that your project *requires*.

E.g. lets say that your project only requires Flask:

```
$ pip install Flask
$ pip freeze
click==6.7
Flask==0.12.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
Werkzeug==0.12.2
```

As you can see by installing Flask many more packages were installed, but you don't have to list those in your `requirements.txt`, as they are not your projects requirements, they are Flask's requirements.

Therefore you should construct your `requirements.txt` manually. What I usually do is `pip install Flask; pip freeze |grep Flask` and copy the line `Flask==0.12.2` to my `requirements.txt`, doing this every time I install something with `pip`.

Comment: But what if Flask itself needs to use those modules? For example, in my code I never explicitly import Jinja2, but I know for a fact that I am using it. I feel like manually excluding files simply because I'm not using them is a risky decision.

Comment: When you do `pip install -r requirements.txt` it will see Flask and start to install Flask, in which process Flask will list its own requirements, therefore also installing those. I.e. you need Flask, Flask requires Jinja2.